# Toggling hide-visible overflow onclick

Tags: jquery, css, onclick, overflow

I'm a newbie in JQuery so I ask you help to me.. How I can hide overflow in html after click on dropdown button menu and after closing toggle overflow as visible.

I tried this, but it allowed only to hide the overflow. Then how I can toggle hide-scroll?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.button').on('click', function() {
      $('html').css("overflow", "hidden");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-value)'s callBack function,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.button').on('click', function() {
      $('html').css("overflow", function(_,val){ 
           return val == "hidden" ? "scroll" : "hidden";
      });
   });
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2ojbtbg6/)

Comment: @R.Ibragimov Glad to help! :)