# Stop with scrolling (when menu is folding out)

Tags: scroll, menu

I'm currently working on my website: http://jellekok.com/new/index.html
I made a menu which works how i wanted, only one thing is not working yet. If you open the top right menu, you shouldn't be able to scroll. Only if you go back to the website you should be able to scroll again.

Does someone know how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36113263/toggling-hide-visible-overflow-onclick (to hide the scrollbars)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to keep the menu fixed. Please use "position:fixed" for the menu.

Comment: yeah that works, thanks! but the scrollbar (of the body element) is still visible

Comment: I couldn't see you page. maybe you can set z-index to put menu at the front end.

Comment: i found the solution, see my post above. website is here if you want to see the solution: http://jellekok.com/new/index.php